# Asp.net Mvc Ajax Json (post Array)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

javascript\jQuery:

```
 var items = new Array();

 var obj { Begin: "444", End: "end" };

 items.push(obj);
 items.push(obj);

  var request = {
             DateStart: $("#DateStart").val(),
             mass: items
         };


 $.post("/Home/Index", request, null,
 "json");
```

C# Mvc Index Controller

```
 public class MyClass
     {
        public string Begin;
        public string End;
     }

     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]        
     public ActionResult Index(            
         string DateStart,            
         MyClass []mass)
     {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(mass[0].Begin);
     }
```

how to execute this code? thanks.

Comment: Here is the right http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2010/05/aspnet-mvc-and-jquery-part-4-advanced.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POSTing array to ASP.NET MVC Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402036/jquery-ajax-posting-array-to-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1):

U can't pass   `mass: items` and expect it to be serialized as a JSON array automatically, you will need to either iterate and construct the JSON (bad plan) or use a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)(good plan)

Comment: +1 for good link. The function to be executed is `JSON.stringify(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try write code as below:

```
var option = {
  url: '/Home/Index',
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(request),
  dataType: 'html',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
  }
};
$.ajax(option);
```