# jQuery Ajax POSTing array to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, http-post

I'm missing something here. I've got this jQuery JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/update-note-order",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        orderedIds: orderedIds,
        unixTimeMs: new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

Where `orderedIds` is a JavaScript number array (e.g. `var orderedIds = [1, 2]`).

The handling `Controller` method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateNoteOrder(long[] orderedIds, long unixTimeMs)
{
    ...
}
```

When I put a `Debugger.Break()` in `UpdateNoteOrder()`, `orderedIds` is `null` in the Watch window. (`unixTimeMs`, however, has a numeric value.)

How do I pass the number array through `$.ajax()` such that `orderedIds` is a `long[]` in my controller?

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Passing-an-Array-to-MVC-Action-via-AJAX

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Just set the [`traditional`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) parameter to `true`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/update-note-order",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        orderedIds: orderedIds,
        unixTimeMs: new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

Since jquery 1.4 this parameter exists because the mechanism to serialize objects into query parameters has changed.

Comment: Unfortunately in my Rails application, I get only last element of the array. I verified that browser is sending array correctly. In above example, I replaced `orderedIds: orderedIds` with `'orderedIds[]': orderedIds` to make it work for Rails.

Comment: Great one. Instead of using Viewmodel for a simple string array, traditional true does it. upvoted !

Comment: I've spent an unbelievable amount of time trying to figure out this issue in my code and I stumbled across this gem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to turn orderedId's into a param array, or the controller won't see it

```
$.param({ orderedIds: orderedIds });
```

in your code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/update-note-order",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        orderedIds: $.param({ orderedIds: orderedIds }),
        unixTimeMs: new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work. In UpdateNoteOrder, orderedIds is still null.

Comment: if it doesn't work, check your code first, this is taken directly from the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ You may want to be sure you are correct before rejecting an answer

Comment: I can confirm also that this doesn't work (I wrote a sample application in order to test it).

Comment: I tested with 1.3.2, I see now the changes were in 1.4. I guess I didn't update jquery recently.

Comment: in jquery 1.3.2 you don't even need `$.param`, it will work out of the box. Unfortunately in jquery 1.4 this behavior has changed.

Comment: Perhaps best to just remove this answer?