# Binding MVC model in controller which has a complex array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Most of my model is populated using `$('form').serializeArray()`, however an array of objects that form a paged grid need to be populated from its manager.
For example:

```
public JsonResult SubmitForm(MyViewModel input)
{
```

...

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Display(Name = "Name")]
  public string GridName { get; set; }

  [Display(Name = "Description")]
  public string GridDescription { get; set; }

  public GridRow[] GridRows { get; set; }
```

The name and description would be picked up by `serializeArray()`, no issues there. If the `GridRow` is a `string[]`, then it accepts me simply pushing multiple instances to it into the serialized array that jquery made:

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray();
for (var i in gridData) {
   data.push({ name: 'GridRows', value: gridData[i].id });
}
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/Central/Results/SubmitForm',
   dataType: "json",
   data: data,
```

This way I can at least get an array of the IDs. However, it does not allow me to push the entire object into it (`gridData[i]`) when I want to populate the proper data type. I always get a null value when it reaches the controller.

Any idea how I need to handle the data in order for MVC to populate the model correctly? Thanks.

Comment: If you're sending multiple rows, then I'd say you're sending multiple models. You'd need to change your controller signature to `public JsonResult SubmitForm(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> input)`

Comment: There is only 1 name and description in the model, but many rows. So its a many models inside a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out just need to add a line and property reference, and add each variable separately.

```
        for (var i in gridData) {
           for (var j in gridData[i]) {
              data.push({ name: 'GridRows[' + i + '].' + j, value: gridData[i][j] });
           }
        }
```

Edit: Just thought I'd post my updated helper method I wrote a while ago for this.

```
function serializeArray(obj, data, name) {
   /// <summary>Turns an object into an MVC standard array of values </summary>
   /// <param name="obj" type="Object">Object to serialise (required)</param>
   /// <param name="data" type="Array">Array to append data to end of (optional)</param>
   /// <param name="name" type="String">Name prefix for all entries (optional/ignore)</param>

   if (!data || !(data instanceof Array)) {
      data = [];
   }
   if (obj instanceof Array) {
      if (!name) {
         throw "Need an object name when converting an array";
      }
      for (var index = 0; index < obj.length; index++) {
         data = serializeArray(obj[index], data, name + '[' + index + ']');
      }
   } else if (obj instanceof Object) {
      for (var property in obj) {
         if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            data = serializeArray(obj[property], data, name ? (name + '.' + property) : property);
         }
      }
   } else {
      data.push({ name: name, value: obj });
   }
   return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is related to having to set the `traditional` option to `true` in your Ajax post. jQuery handles arrays a little differently than you'd expect, in terms of when they are posted to MVC controller actions.

So do this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/Central/Results/SubmitForm',
   dataType: "json",
   traditional: true,
   data: data,
   ...
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4402080/213902) for more details.