# How to pass a list of id's in a AJAX request to the Server in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

In a AJAX request to the server in MVC, how can I pass a list of id's to the controller's action function?

I accept with or without use of Html helpers.

I know MVC's model binder has no problem when it comes to simple types like `int`, `string` and `bool`.

Is it something like I have to use and array instead in the action?

I don't care if I have to use an `array` or `List` and even if the strings I `int` or `strings` I can always convert them. I just need them on the server.
My List ids gives null at the moment.

Javascript:

```
var ids= [1,4,5];
// ajax request with ids..
```

MVC Action:

```
public ActionResult ShowComputerPackageBuffer(List<int> ids) // ids are null
{
    // build model ect..
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**EDIT:** Added my AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#spanComputerPackagesBuffer').on('click', function () {
        var ids = $('#divComputerPackagesBuffer').data('buffer');
        console.log('bufferIds: ' + bufferIds);
        var data = {
            ids: ids
        };

        var url = getUrlShowComputerPackageBuffer();
        loadTable(url, "result", data);
    });
});

// AJAX's
function loadTable(url, updateTargetId, data) {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "html",
        data: data
    })
    .done(function (result) {
        $('#' + updateTargetId).html(result);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errMsg = textStatus.toUpperCase() + ": " + errorThrown + '. Could not load HTML.';
        alert(errMsg);
    });
};

// URL's
function getUrlShowComputerPackageBuffer() {
    return '@Url.Action("ShowComputerPackageBuffer", "Buffer")';
};
```

**SOLUTIONS: // Thanks to @aherrick comment. I missed the good old "traditional"**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("ShowComputerPackageBuffer", "Buffer")',
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {
        bufferIds: bufferIds
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you make your AJAX request?

Comment: @OmriAharon sure one moment

Comment: Use `traditional` parameter.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402036/jquery-ajax-posting-array-to-asp-net-mvc-controller

Comment: Ahh yes this rings some bells! I think it will help alot, I will try it now.

Comment: @aherrick Brilliant it works. If you make an answer I will accept it. I will edit my solution also for others.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `traditional` parameter and set it to `true`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/URL",
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {}
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this one (I've checked it):

```
$(function () {
        var ids = [1, 4, 5];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '@Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController")',
            data: JSON.stringify( { ids: ids })
        }).done(function () {

        });
    });
```

You have to make sure your `contentType` is `application/json` and your data is stringified.

Comment: I have tryed it, and bufferIds (or ids) is still null on server. How does your action signatur look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult SaveSomething(int[] requestData) 
//or
public ActionResult SaveSomething(IEnumerable<int> requestData)
```

Using Action Result you cannot receive JSON object:

Using Controler:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route( "api/Controller/SaveSomething" )]
    public object SaveTimeSheet( int[] requestData )
    {
        try
        {
            doSomethingWith( requestData );

            return new
            {
                status = "Ok",
                message = "Updated!"
            };
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            return new
            {
                status = "Error",
                message = ex.Message
            };
        }


}
```

java script:

```
var ids = [1,4,5];
var baseUrl: 'localhost/yourwebsite'
$.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl + '/api/Controller/SaveSomething',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(ids),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result != undefined) {
                            window.location.href = window.location.href;
                        }
                    },
                    async: false,
                });
```

Comment: Why did you use async:false in this case?

Comment: No reason, just to unlock the page until response is received,  synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser.