# Django rest framework POST with a foreign key field

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

How can I use a jquery ajax call to `POST` a new record for a model that contains a `ManyToMany` field?

My model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  bar = models.ManyToManyField(Qux, blank=True)
  baz = CharField(max_length=15)

class Qux(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

My js:

```
values = {
    bar: ???,
    baz: 'test'
}

$.ajax({
                url: '/api/foo/',
                type: 'PUT',
                data: values,
                success: function(e){
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('error')
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would be to pass a list of IDs corresponding to the `Qux` objects with which you want to form a relationship. You can then use those IDs in an `add` method in your view.

Here's a good SO post on passing a list of IDs via ajax: [How to pass a list of id's in a AJAX request to the Server in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855763/how-to-pass-a-list-of-ids-in-a-ajax-request-to-the-server-in-mvc)